# Whitespaces in Java code

Tags: java, string, whitespace

What is the preferred way of producing a String which holds a sequence of whitespaces of an arbitrary length? Is it this way:

```
final String spaces = "   "; //three white spaces
```

or is there a better way?

Comment: Where /w is a whitespace?

Comment: for what ? What is the problem that you are trying to solve ?

Comment: when someone reads code, it is difficult to see what the padding is - whether it is two tabs or few whitespaces etc.

Comment: I think @SimoneGianni means that `/w` does not equal whitespace in Java. That sequence will literally just output `/w/w/w` into your target. Nor is `\w` whitespace in Java, so can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: ah! I meant escape character which represents a whitespace. I apologize. Is there any?

Comment: No, there is no escape sequence for the standard space character (unless you want to use a Unicode code point). See the [tutorial page about Characters in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say personal preference, as long as the person that will maintain the code after you know what's happening that's what is most important.

Here is another option:

```
final String spaces = String.format("%"+ 3 +"s", " ");
```

Just to add on from @Freiheit, this would be another solution to the problem.

```
final String spaces = StringUtils.leftPad("", 3).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to pad or indent other Strings. Using something like [Apache StringUtils.leftPad](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad(java.lang.String,%20int)) is a much better option than having whitespace String variables.